# Typed arrays in TypeScript - what is the difference between Array<Foo> and Foo[]?

Tags: arrays, syntax, typescript

In TypeScript I have a class `Foo`

```
class Foo {}
```

I want array of instances of Foo. What is the difference between

```
var foos : Array<Foo>;
```

and

```
var foos : Foo[];
```

It seems to me that both define array of instances of given type, is there any difference at all?

**EDIT:** What are the names of these constructs? How do I correctly refer to them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are both identical as type annotations, so you can use whichever you prefer.

The Array syntax has only been available since generics were added.

Comment: I have edited the question a bit - do you happen to know what are the names of these constructs? How do I correctly refer to them?

Comment: The square brackets are an 'array literal' and the <T> version is a 'generic type with a type argument' - although in this case they are both 'type annotations' too.