# Differences in Typescript array literal syntax

Tags: typescript, typescript1.7

Typescript allows one to define an Array with either syntax:

```
var myStrArry1: string[] = [];
```

or

```
var myStrArry1: Array<string> = [];
```

The compiled output appears to be the same. Does the compiler treat them identically, or are there some quirks to be aware of?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typed arrays in TypeScript - what is the difference between Array<Foo> and Foo\[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357424/typed-arrays-in-typescript-what-is-the-difference-between-arrayfoo-and-foo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the compiler treat them identically, or are there some quirks to be aware of?

They are identical. I prefer syntax 1

Answer (score 2):

From the [typescript documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md), they are treated identically, one is simply a shorthand notation for the other. The compiler doesn't care which one you use.

Answer (score 1):

This is the paragraph from TypeScript specification: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.8.4 that specifies that both syntaxes are equivalent:

> Alternatively, array types can be written using the `Array<T>`
>   notation. For example, the types above are equivalent to
>
> `Array<string | number>   Array<() => string>`