# Specifying typescript array types

Tags: typescript

In [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) you can specify an array of numbers type as either `number[]` or `Array<number>`. Is there a difference or reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887022/differences-in-typescript-array-literal-syntax

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a difference or reason to choose one over the other?

No. `number[]` is just a shorthand.

## Origin

This is because TS the very original versions, didn't have generics so a special syntax for arrays was created.